# Trivial pursuit : bash environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I know this works:

```
FNAME="$(basename $LD_PRELOAD)"
FNAME="${FNAME%.*}"
```

Can this be expressed in a single line? These are two unsuccessful attempts, thus far:

```
${$(basename LD_PRELOAD)%.*}


${`$(basename $LD_PRELOAD)`%.*}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the use case? If you're writing a wrapper script, you could consider using zsh instead of bash - which would allow you to use the **r**oot and **t**ail expansion modifiers ex. `${LD_PRELOAD:r:t}`

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question, show us the value(s) of `LD_PRELOAD` you need to be able to handle, and the output you would expect from those values.

Comment: For example, what output would you expect if `LD_PRELOAD=/foo/bar.baz.d`?

Comment: `FNAME="$(basename $LD_PRELOAD)"` doesn't work if `LD_PRELOAD` contains spaces. Always quote your variables `FNAME="$(basename "$LD_PRELOAD")"` unless you **need** to not quote one for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78037879/10477326). Adapted for your situation, it would be the following:

```bash
FNAME="${LD_PRELOAD//@(*\/|.*)}"
```

Do note that LD_PRELOAD can contain multiple paths separated by `:`, and my answer has the same limitation as your `basename` attempt.

Also, my answer does `%%` instead of your `%`, which means that it will remove everything after the first dot, not the last dot. This is probably what you want, because your uses case seems like it wants `libQt5Gui` for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.15` not `libQt5Gui.so.5`. I don't know of a way to make the one-liner with `${//}` do `%` instead of `%%`. If you want the `.so`, you could just add it after the quotes.

> Your goal of "to strip the path and extension off of a script name so that only the base name is left" is actually possible in a single Bash expression without subshells or commands. Before facing the XY problem of nested parameter expansion, it's important to ask whether [`${parameter%word}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=the%20resultant%20list.-,%24%7Bparameter%25word%7D,-%24%7Bparameter%25%25) and [`${parameter##word}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=%23word%7D-,%24%7Bparameter%23%23word%7D,-Remove%20matching%20prefix) are the right tools for the job. Since this is a filepath, it is possible to use [`${parameter//pattern/string}`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=%24%7Bparameter//pattern/string%7D) with the [`@(pattern‐list)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion:%7E:text=the%20given%20patterns-,%40(pattern%2Dlist),-Matches%20one%20of) glob provided by `shopt -s extglob` (enabled by default).